# Dynamic change of the class of an HTML element not working effectively

Tags: php, javascript, html, events, mootools

I've written an HTML page that contains a form. The form is checked by a PHP page by having at the beginning of the HTML page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools/core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools/more.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcheck/lang/fr.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/formcheck/formcheck.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
       new FormCheck('form');
});
</script>
```

The problem is that I add dynamically a class to an HTML element after the page is loaded under some conditions.

The following code sample of the HTML page is a radio button to know if the visitor of the page has a car. If she/he puts yes then the class 'validate['required']' is added to select element number of cars meaning the user must choose a value (number of cars). Otherwise the user has no car and then doesn't have to choose and the default empty string is accepted and transmitted.

```
<input type="radio" name="cars" value="yes" onclick="document.getElementById('number_of_cars').setAttribute('class','validate[\'required\']');">oui
<input type="radio" name="cars" value="no" checked="checked">no



<label>How many cars do you have ? :</label>        
<select name="number_of_cars" id="number_of_cars">
<option value="">-</option>
<option value="01" >01</option>
<option value="02" >02</option>
<option value="03" >03</option>
</select>
```

The problem I have is that when I check with Firebug the HTML element has the class 'validate['required']' when needed (radio button yes) but the PHP page doesn't seem to work because the form is transmitted even if the user hasn't choosed a number of cars.

My guess is that the event "domready" on the Javascript part of my HTML page is not appropriate but I don't know what to do.

Edit: I've changed the javascript element to onChange but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: PHP will check form AFTER the form is transmitted - or you are using some framework to do this ?

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly the problem is. Is it that your client side validation script isn't working (if so we need more details on that)? The validation should be happening in the onsubmit handler of the form if it isn't already. Either way though your php script should be able to deal with invalid input to avoid any potential problems due to client side validation failure (eg no javascript) or malicious attacks taking advantage of whatever error causes things to fail.

Comment: Yes I'm using some kind of framework because the alerts for the fields not appropriate in the form are displayed using the script of my HTML page at the beginning and I think the problem here is that the event being domready the page is only checked only one time and not every time a change occurs.

Comment: @Chris The problem is that the form is submitted even if there is a compulsory select with no content inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The window.addEvent('domready') is part of the [MooTools library](http://mootools.net/), it is not part of Javascript itself. It seems to me that you are not using that, so you should either add the MooTools script to your html, or use the onLoad event.</del>

MooTools is used

**Edit**

Either that, or the value you send with the FormCheck object is wrong. FormCheck needs an id and not a tagname, so you should at least have somewhere:

```
<form id="myForm">

new FormCheck('myForm');
```

**Edit 2**

If you're already using MooTools, it's best to use the built-in event handlers. Direct approaches like onClick and onLoad should be avoided because of cross-browser issues. MooTools takes care of that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('cars').addEvent('click', function() {
      $('number_of_cars').addClass("validate['required']");
    });

    new FormCheck('form');
  });
</script>
```

MooTools needs id's for this to work, so:

```
<input type="radio" name="cars" id="cars" value="yes">
```

**Edit 3**

Also read the docs of FormCheck carefully. They contain lots of sample code: http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/

Docs: http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't put I used MooTools. I've corrected my code accordingly.

Comment: I've tried to put the id of my form in new Formcheck but it doesn't work. For your first suggestion (onLoad event) the change on the page being dynamic how could onLoad work ?

Comment: onLoad should be avoided if you're already using MooTools anyway. MooTools domready is better because it decreases cross-browser issues you get with pure JavaScript. I've edited my answer thoroughly so I hope it helps.

Comment: Your code works great, thanks a lot ! I only needed to change it a little bit (as suggested in my edition of your post) on my computer.